# NHibernate Envers - how to audit revisions on a separate database?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-envers

I'm using Nhibernate Envers and I want Envers to save audit info on a separate database to keep things cleaner/more maintainable.

I'm using this fluent configuration:

```
var enversCfg = new NHibernate.Envers.Configuration.Fluent.FluentConfiguration()

enversCfg.Audit(GetDomainEntities())
nhCfg.SetEnversProperty(ConfigurationKey.DefaultCatalog, "nhibernate_testAU")
```

but when I try to create the schema, I get a HibernateException (The specified schema name "nhibernate_testAU" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.)

for what it's worth, my backend is SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to actually creating the database, I specified the schema to "dbo".

```
c.SetEnversProperty(ConfigurationKey.DefaultSchema, "dbo");  
c.SetEnversProperty(ConfigurationKey.DefaultCatalog, "MyCatalog_Audit");
```

Also, I have my own RevistionEntity class, so, I needed to add the catalog and schema to my hbm.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="MyAssembly" namespace="MyNamespace">
  <class name="MyRevisionEntity" table="REVINFO" catalog="MyCatalog_Audit" schema="dbo">
    <id name="Id" column="MyRevisionEntityId">
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="AuditDate"></property>
    <property name="UserName"></property>
    <!--modifiedEntityNames-->
    <set name="ModifiedEntityNames" table="REVCHANGES"  catalog="MyCatalog_Audit" schema="dbo">
      <key column="REV"/>
      <element column="ENTITYNAME" type="string"/>
    </set>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

HTH

Chuck

Comment: using `c.SetEnversProperty(ConfigurationKey.DefaultCatalog, "MyCatalog_Audit.dbo");` also works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually create the catalog/database. AFAIK - NH's SchemaExport don't create database/catalog (or schemas) for you.